Vercel cookie is not getting deleted after log out
I have deployed my MERN app in Vercel. I am having an issue with logout. After I log out, if I do a refresh, I get logged in again. The cookie is not getting deleted, but it is getting deleted in the local environment.
res.cookie('token', '', {
        expires: new Date(0),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
       
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "logged out"
    })

I have used null in place of "".
Tried this too as suggested by chatGPT.
exports.logout = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {

    res.cookie('token', '', {
        expires: new Date(0),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'None',
        domain: process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN,
        path: '/'
    });

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "logged out"
    })
})


but nothing worked

Please add the code of how res variable is declared

Looks like second snippet is setting the Cookie or session to a new sesison instead of clearing existing one.
Use builtin response function to clear cookie
res.clearCookie(name, [ options ])

Name: It is the name of the cookie which is to be cleared.
Options: It is an object that can have various properties like domain, encode, path, secure, etc.
Set cookie
    res.cookie('mytoken', '', {
// add your remaining cookie prefence key value,
domain :process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN
    

Clear cookie
res.clearCookie('mytoken', {domain :'process.env.COOKIE_DOMAIN'
});

So this snippet clears the cookie from the preferred domain and it should help you to logout clean.
